DMS Source Data and Latency spike nightly
I'm using a SQL Server on-prem source for a DMS to replicate to a SQL Server RDS. Every night, at about midnight, I'm seeing a spike of ~1.6M CDC incoming changes on my DMS task, but nothing is making anywhere near that many data changes on-prem. It takes about 8hr to get caught up, with a max latency of about 5hr. The latency hits its max about an hour or two before it's caught back up. Otherwise, it seems caught up for the remainder of the day. Also comparing the count of the PK column of one of the main tables, I'm about 65.6k records short in my RDS.
I don't have CDC on at the source db level or any of the source tables, but I thought I didn't need it because all tables being replicated have PKs

You've described a number of happenings but does your question have a question?

There is some churn. Can you trace your source for a day?

Ran a trace on the source. Implementing some changes to some nightly processes to see if they are the source of the data changes
